# UITableViewCell height problems

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, autolayout, cell

I'm trying to configure my tableViewCell but some problems with layouts.

This is my view controller:

[image]

Here is my xib file with cell:

[image]

And how it works:

[image]

Code for ViewController:

```
class BooksListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var booksTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setView()
    }
    
    private func setView() {
        searchBar.placeholder = "Поиск"
        booksTableView.delegate = self
        booksTableView.dataSource = self
        booksTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BooksTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "bookCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = booksTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookCell", for: indexPath) as? BooksTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
   
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: just write the size you want here -- > func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        50
    }

Comment: It works, thank you. But is there some ways to do it automatically. Just cell resized height depending on content?

Comment: @aLikan - it looks like you haven't set any constraints on your outermost (horizontal) stack view... you should constrain all 4 sides to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: @willow Don't do that. The proper solution is to fix the constraints on the cell. And never use `heightForRowAt` to return a single hardcoded value. If you have a case where all rows are the same height, don't implement `heightForRowAt`. Instead, set the table view's `rowHeight` property. It's far more efficient. But that doesn't apply to this case since the OP needs each row to be a different height using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHightSize * UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 667 
}
```